# What is the invert operation of bytes repr() in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = b'\x00\x01'
ra = repr(a)   # ra == "b'\\x00\\x01'"
assert invert_repr(ra) == a
```

What is the correct form of invert_repr? string_escape & unicode_escape?

Comment: Are you using `repr()` to serialise and unserialise data? Don't, Python syntax is not meant to be a serialisation format. Use pickle, marshall or json instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `eval` or equivalent:

```
from ast import literal_eval
a = b'\x00\x01'
ra = repr(a)
assert literal_eval(ra) == eval(ra) == a # no error
```

[`ast.literal_eval` is safer than `eval`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15197673/2301450)

Comment: Yes, but it is really slow. Could you give me a string-based operation?

Comment: @ShenLei: no, there are no other options. You have a Python byte string literal, these are your options to interpret it again. Why do you need this?

Comment: Because I read data from a text file and printed failed-to-decode content with repr() to another file. Now I want to process the latter.

Comment: @ShenLei: then why are you complaining about speed? You are debugging, not writing a performance-sensitive application. And why not just pickle then?

Comment: En, some kind of debugging. The text file is about 2GB and mixed with several encodings and formats. There are ~1000 such files. I have to process them round-by-round. So eval() is much slower than simple string operation. pickle is not human-readable. I hope there is a decoder to parse '\x??' string.

Comment: @ShenLei: why did you write 2GB using `repr()` representation instead of writing the bytes directly? (it is not very hard to parse a Python `bytes` literal  in C without `ast.literal_eval()`  but you shouldn't need to -- here're [lexical definitions for the `bytes` literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals))